# Unable to connect to localhost when working in the domain

Tags: visual-studio, iis, localhost, iis-express

Working in the local environment I'm quite often getting errors on communication between the visual studio, IIS, IIS-Express and the browser (any combination). Everything is working on closing down the computer and doesn't any more when the computer restarts. Problems have started when the computer joined the domain.

Answer (score 0):

I've spend hours searching for a solution to the problem. It looks as Widows Defender is to blame which is triggering different rules after I've joining the domain. It is enough to switch off the firewall, start any web application and enable the firewall. Simple (yet annoying) but working (what is most important).

Comment: Windows Firewall has different profiles for different network environments (domain or not, and more). Though it might be documented by Microsoft, people might find it hard to find.

Comment: I've matched all settings (ticks) so they are same for the domain network, yet no luck so far. Adding application exclusions doesn't work either. I don't want to add a blank port exception as that opens security for abuse. Microsoft could have done it a bit better..